# How to POST javascript Blob to JAX-WS Web service

Tags: javascript, web-services, post, blob, jax-ws

I am using the Mozilla Web API and specifically the blob data type.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

I am trying to post to a web service written in JAX-WS and pass an audio file blob as a parameter. I am unsure what parameter I need for my web service in order to receive the blob.

JavaScript example snippet...

```
var blob; // initialise to some variable
var url = 'myUrl';
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
console.log(xhttp.responseText);
}
};

xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.send('?param=' + blob);
```

JAX-WS Web service method

```
@POST
@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String postMessage(@QueryParam("param") byte [] test){
   //do something with byte [] test
   return "Success";
}
```

I am unsure how to set up this functionality and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What file type are you trying to send? The shown JAX-WS service only receives text. Is the API your own or something external?

Comment: I am trying to send an OGG file which is produced using the Mozilla API. I know that the web service is currently incorrect... I just need help with the parameters and what needs to be produced/consumed.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you: http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/web-services/java-web-services-binary-data-transfer-example-base64-encoding
Basically, you will not want to send binary data as a query paramet. Instead you POST it as the HTTP body. See section 3 for the upload implementation and section 7 on the HTTP tests.

Comment: To send binary data you would do `xhttp.send(blob);`, to consume it... idk. If you know how to consume multipart/form-data, you can send a FormData object with the blob in it `var fd = new FormData();fd.append('file',blob,'name.ogg');xhttp.send(fd);`

Answer (score 0):

Just use **Binary Data** transfer and **MTOM** to optimize it with JAX-WS web-service.

From [Oracle Help Center](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm#WSADV130):

> 1. **Annotate the data types that you are going to use as an MTOM attachment. (Optional)**
>
>    Depending on your programming model, you can annotate your Java class
>      or WSDL to define the content types that are used for sending binary
>      data. This step is optional. By default, XML binary types are mapped
>      to Java byte[].
> 2. **Enable MTOM on the Web service.**
> 3. **Enable MTOM on the client of the Web service.**
> 4. **Set the attachment threshold.**
>
>    Set the attachment threshold to specify when the xs:binary64 data is
>      sent inline or as an attachment.